# Python undesirably expressing answers to certain mathematical equations in scientific notation

Tags: python

Say I want to find the answer to 50^15. If I type it in like this it gives me the answer in scientific notation:

```
>>> 51**(30/2)
4.107264216077056e+25
```

If I type it in like this, it doesn't give me scientific notation:

```
>>> 51**15
41072642160770556400888251
```

I know they are both representing the same number, but it is causing problems with certain mathematical functions. For example with gcd:

```
>>> gcd(4.107264216077056e+25+1,77)
1.0

>>> gcd(41072642160770556400888251+1,77)
11
```

I get the wrong answer when I use scientific notation. Why does it do this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Float vs. integers.

Comment: `51**int(30/2)` - see the difference?

Comment: Or use `30//2` to get int division

Answer (score 1):

Integer division.

The result of `30 / 2` , `type (30/2)` is a float

The result of `30 // 2` , `type (30//2)` is an int.

When you compute 50 ** x, it matters what the type of variable x is. if x is of type float, the result will be a floating point number. if x is of type int, the result will be an integer number

Answer (score 0):

This is a difference between python-2 and python-3.
In python-3 the regular or classic division '/' treats the numbers like floats even if they are integers, so the result is a float as well. To get integer result you need to use integer division operator or cast the result:

```
>>> 30/2
15.0
>>> 30//2
15
>>> int(30/2)
15
>>> 31/2
15.5
>>> 31//2
15
>>> int(31/2)
15
```

So in your case use `51**(30//2)` or `51**int(30/2)`.

Curious "trap" here is that integers in python have infinite precision while floats do not. Which means you have to cast before power operator reduces the precision of your calculation:

```
>>> 51**15
41072642160770556400888251
>>> int(51**(30/2))
41072642160770559363776512
>>> 51**int(30/2)
41072642160770556400888251
>>> int(51**(30/2))-(51**int(30/2))
2962888261
```

read more in the official tutorial:
https://docs.python.org/3.1/tutorial/introduction.html#numbers

Answer (score 0):

`30/2` is a float but you can easily integerise it using `int(30/2)` and python won't give it in scientific notation.